# Find the value of k which makes f a density function.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Observe the following probability density function for a continuous random variable X
$$f (x) = \begin{cases}
k\sqrt x (1-x) &\text{ for }x\in(0,1)\\
 0 &\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Find the value of $k$ which makes $f$ a density function.

My thoughts, is it the integral from $0$ to $1$ of $f(x)$?

Comment: It is actually the inverse of that number. The integral must be equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We must choose $k$ so that $\int_0^1 k(1-x)\sqrt{x}\,dx=1$. So we need to evaluate the integral.

For the evaluation, let $x=u^2$. Then $dx=2u\,du$, and we find $k$ such that
$$\int_0^1 2k(u^2-u^4)\,du=1.$$

Comment: So is k 15/4 then?

Comment: Yes, $k=\frac{15}{4}$.